# How do I chose which db to use?

Tags: mysql, bash

I want to insert data with a csv-file. I want to do this by having this row in a bash script:

```
mysql -uusername -ppassword "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'CSVname.csv'  INTO TABLE table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

But I'm not sure where in this string I can select which DB to use. Only which table. 
I get it to work if I enter it manually with "use dbname" and then LOAD DATA etc..

Can anyone please help?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A simple look at the manual would have helped you here, it did me.

All you need to do is add the database name in front of the table name like this:

```
mysql -uxxx -p yyy "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'CSVname.csv'  INTO TABLE 
databasename.table_name  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
```

Comment: Oh, embarrassing. Thank you so much for your help!

Comment: I'm sorry. It still won't work. I also checked the manual an extra time this time. But still cant figure it out. mysql -u -p "LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/csvfile.csv' INTO TABLE excel.test FIELDS TERMINATED ',' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'"
ERROR 1102 (42000): Incorrect database name 'LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/var/lib/mysql-files/csvfile.csv' INTO TABLE excel.test FIELDS'

Comment: Are you sure you have a table called `excel`

Comment: I'm sure. Though, the dbname is 'excel' and the table is called 'test'.

Comment: Then are you sure you are connecting to the correct MySQL Server? Have you tried adding a `-h hostname`

Comment: I haven't. I'm connecting to localhost. I added -h localhost now right after the password but still the same problem.

Comment: Well I am plumb out of idea's, sorry. Not easy debugging remotely